# Water gets cold when central heating is on?

Tags: boiler, hot-water, central-heating

I have a Vaillant System Boiler with an external cylinder to store hot water. After heating the water, If I switch on the central heating the water supplier to the taps/showers gets cold after a short while.

First we heat the water supply to taps in the external cylinder by switching on the hot water. Maybe after while 30 mins to 1 hour we may switch on the central heating on but the hot water switch is switched off as its on a timer

Please can you explain why and if there is an issue how to resolve?

Based in UK

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW5aN.jpg)

Comment: Pictures are worth 1000 words.  Also, what water gets cold?  From your limited description it's hard to tell if you have a hot water house heating system and that's what's getting cold, or if what is getting cold is your hot water supply to the sinks/showers/etc.?  When you switch on the central heating, does your boiler fire up to maintain the hot water?

Comment: Hi, the hot water being supplied to taps and shower is getting cold? When the central heating is on the water heating is switched off but it was on before the central heating was switched on and heated the water and stored in external cylinder tank

Comment: What sort of central heating do you have, and how does that heat feed your external tank?  My *guess* (based on your description and my parents' system) is that you have a boiler with multiple zone valves, and one of those zones heats your external tank.  It sounds like there's some sort of control that doesn't allow the zone heating your water to be active when your central heating is activated.  If that's the case, is this a new situation or has it always been this way?

Comment: It has always been the case. I can have the hot water and the central heating on at the same time. But if i had already heated the water and stored in the tank after I switch on the central heating it would go cold